# Property 'cat' does not exist on type

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

I have a problem, in the portion of code below:

```
getPorts() {
let brands = [];

this.vehicles.forEach(country => {
  country.brands.forEach(brand => {
    brand.cat = country ;
    brands.push(brand);
  });
});
console.log(brands);
this.brands = brands;
}
```

the error is :

```
Property 'cat' does not exist on type '{ 'brand': string; 'flag': string; }'.
```

how to resolve this problem.

her's a portion of data which i use:

```
{
  'cat': 'A',
  'brands': [
    {
      'brand': 'Adamoli','flag':'https://restcountries.eu/data/ita.svg'
    },

  ]
},
```

Comment: You are iterating over the "brands" collection, "cat" is not a property on the objects within that collection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe one of the brands does not have a property 'cat'.

It's difficult to answer this without seeing your data model. Can you console.log out "this.vehicles".

It looks like the portion of data is the "country", which contains the "cat". But you're trying to get "cat" from the "brand" which doesn't contain that property.